# Two directions of "Identify"

Tags: word-usage, passive-voice

I have a question about the usage of the verb "*identify*".  Could "*identify*" be used in two directions like the following:

> 1. John Doe was ***identified*** as the intruder of the meeting.
> 2. The intruder of meeting was ***identified*** as John Doe.

?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, the patterns go like this:

**The {previously unknown person, e.g. the intruder} was identified as John Smith.**

and

**{The person we knew as} John Smith has been identified as {someone or something other than we thought: John Jacob Jingleheimer, a spy, a polygamist, a frequent intruder at meetings}**

But you'll no doubt find:

**Joe Doe was identified as the masked intruder.**

rather than the other way around.

"Identified" is more or less synonymous with "shown to be".

Comment: I think both are commonly used. "The suspect has been identified as Damien A. Harrell" ( http://wtkr.com/2015/06/24/officer-involved-in-shooting-near-richneck-road-in-york-co/ ) or "Intruder identified as army veteran" ( http://latino.foxnews.com/latino/news/2014/09/21/secret-service-to-beef-up-security-at-white-house-after-intruder-made-it-to/ ).

Comment: But your examples don't cover the pattern I've identified as odd:  Damien Harrell was identified as the suspect.

Comment: Then I am confused about your answer. You said "you'll no doubt find *Joe identified as masked intruder* rather than the other way around". So I found the other way around. On re-reading, you seem to say both forms are common - is it the use of "was" instead of "has been" that you suggest is different?

Comment: I gave two patterns, which your quotations mirror. The first pattern is `{the unknown} has been identified as {named person}`. The second pattern is `{named person} has been identified as {something|some other named person}.` Then I gave a third less typical pattern `{named person} was identified as {unknown individual}`, that is, the inverse of the first pattern.  The third pattern is less typical in that with it, the complement of "identified as" is the unknown/unnamed/unidentified rather than the known/identified. In the third pattern, "identified as" is almost like the predicate "is".

Comment: The same meaning , with the subtle difference that the emphasis is on  the identification of John Doe in the first sentence, wheras it's on the intruder of the meeting in the second sentence.

Comment: Tromano. Well-explained.